# intermittent SSH with ssh_exchange_identification error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

My ssh connection to my server works every 30 min for around 10 min.

Things that I figure out that might be the problem:

- The server is underload (it is a
  database server), but on those spare
  moments that I can connect, it is
  still under the same load, which
  doesnt make sense.
- The server is a ubuntu, and the consolekit was using a lot of virtual memory. Restarted the consolekit and it seems to be using a right amount of memory now.
- It is not the host alows or deny. Those are setup properly.
- It is not a firewall problem. Those settings were working and the same settings are working for other similar machines.
- It is on the ec2. Amazon cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the logging level in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server and see if anything useful is in the logs under /var/logs after that.  Also you should consider starting your sshd with `-d` for debug mode and see if you can find anything interesting that way.

Another good troubleshooting technique is to start sshd with -d and use `strace -p <pid>` to log the system calls made by your ssh servers.  That could tell you if it's hanging on accessing a particular file for example.

Answer (score 0):

That often comes from an inability to write to the /var area of your system, we see this from time to time on our system, especially if /var goes to read only. check that via cat /proc/mounts ( use this not ANY other method as they can be fooled, this will not. )

Comment: well... now that the permissions for /var has been changed and I can't ssh to my amazon instance... any hope left?